# How to override the css aplied by a aspx control using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, controls, jquery-events

I have an AspxFileManager, and I want to distinct a file when they are loaded. To do this, I wanted to add a class that places a border around the element. I didn't work. I achieved it using `.attr('style', 'border: 10px!important');`

However this doesn't work in the beginning because the style is overridden by `ASPx.CreateImportantCssText`

How can I use something to override the css, or which client side event can I use to change the style attribute after the page has completely loaded. 
I have tried

```
$(window).on('pageshow',func)
$(window).on('pageload',func)
```

as well as `EndCallback` for the `fileManager`

Comment: Use `$(window).on('load', func )`

Comment: nope. Fires too soon

Comment: It fires when all resources have loaded (scripts, styles, images,...), excluding async ones. If you're loading stuff after `load`, use a `setTimeout(function(){/* code here*/ }, delayInMiliseconds);` The only other option is to listen to any event that gets triggered by your async loading.

Comment: pageshow fires after load, and it still doesn't work. It first applies the style, then the style is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

```
$(element).css({'border': '10px!important'});
```

This might work as this writes CSS inline of whatever element you pick. And inline CSS with !important attached to it will override all other CSS rules. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: ASPx.CreateImportantCssText overrides all styles. Not by precedent. It literaly writes over the style. Meaning my style is no more. Not that is not applicable due to low priority.